# How to fix sqlite query error where the ? are not replaced by the selection arguments

Tags: android, sqlite

My app is a dictionary and now I am working on making it available offline. The database is downloaded and now we have the situation that there is no internet. I need to use the local database. I get my readable database, and then set up a query. On my own testing phone everything works fine. But now before publishing the update I was trying it on two other phones, just to see that the ? in the selection are not replaced by the values in the selectionArgs.

The debugger just shows that the sql statement was built without replacing anything in the selection.

It works on my phone on Android 8.1, but with the two phone that are lower, it stops working and I am out of ideas.

I also tried changing it to db.rawQuery() but that ended with the same result.

```
    String selection = "eng LIKE ? OR oky LIKE ? OR engpl LIKE ? OR okypl LIKE ? OR engcom LIKE ? OR okycom LIKE ? OR Alternative LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {term, term, term, term, com, com, term};
    String orderBy = "eng, oky ASC";
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DictionaryContract.WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
```

Now I expected the result to give me the terms that fit to the word (term) that was searched for by the user, but instead the cursor is empty, because there is no term containing a question mark.

Especially confusing is that it works on one phone and not on others.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger won't show the resolved ?'s as the replacement of the ?'s is done by the underlying SDK (sqlite implementation) which is in C rather than java.

The best that you can see are the bindArgs e.g. for the following code :-

```
    csr = mDBhlpr.getWritableDatabase().query("table1",null,"id=?",new String[]{"1"},null,null,null);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        long id = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_TABLE1_ID));
    }
```

with a breakpoint at the 1st line then you could get :-

[image]

I don't believe that the issue is with the binding of the arguments, rather that it is elsewhere. You could test this by changing :-

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DictionaryContract.WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
```

To

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DictionaryContract.WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
```

i.e. select all rows, and them write all the rows in the Cursor to the Log.

If still none then the tables on the other devices are empty.
If an Exception occurs then you would have to investigate that.

If this works as expected, then progressively (one by one) add the selection criteria and args.

e.g. first would be

```
 String selection = "eng LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {term};
    String orderBy = "eng, oky ASC";
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DictionaryContract.WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

then :-

```
String selection = "eng LIKE ? OR oky LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {term, term};
String orderBy = "eng, oky ASC";
Cursor cursor = db.query(DictionaryContract.WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null,null);
```

and so on (note finally re-add the order by).

If none of the above works, then your issue (as expected) is elsewhere.